# How can I iterate a beta test of a Chrome extension more quickly when it's always Pending Review after updates?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that's updating several times a day. Right now I'm testing this with a small group of alpha testers who are aware of the pace things are changing. Sometimes, the extension gets stuck in "Pending Review" after I push a new version.

Actually, I haven't gotten through the approval process even once yet as I just started testing. The first time it happened on my first submit, and I simply opened a new listing and it didn't get stuck pending. Now it's pending again, and I have no idea how long I'm going to need to wait - I see people online saying crazy times like 7 days.

So basically, I'm looking for a way to push updates to my testers more quickly and consistently. Is there any alternative way of getting updates out to these testers more quickly? Right now it seems I just have to wait for the extension to be approved. I've tried both unlisted and private (available to specific testers only) and both still have this Pending Review status!

[image]

Comment: Usually it's caused by broad host permissions like `<all_urls>`, `http://*/*` and so on. The only real solution is to redesign the extension to remove such a need and use [optional_permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) instead.

Comment: Huh, ok. I guess that makes sense - I'm using <all_urls>. Unfortunately the nature of what I'm making sort of requires it. Just checked and a well-established competitor extension is using <all_urls> to match. I suppose for early testing I can specify a list of compatible websites or use the optional_permissions which look interesting and potentially fine for my use case. Thanks for the advice!